# Return JSON data in admin Magento

Tags: php, ajax, json, magento

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to create AJAX login inside Magento admin. But I don't know what's going with Magento login function and login action. I'm quite new to Magento and really confused with it...

I already knew there are two place to handle login.

`/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php` (login function)

and

`/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php` (login action)

What I have to do to return JSON data? And the **Url** (`index.php/admin/login` ?) to handle it?

To clear, there are two question I need answer to solve it myself.

1. What is login() function? How it works?
2. What is loginAction() function? How it works?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks everyone!

Comment: As far as I know loginAction will render view, layout for login page, login() will return user entity, then I'm not sure how to return JSON data in this situation....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default flow of Magento Admin form is :

1) When validations are successful and user enters the credentials, magento sends it to Admin/Model/Session.php login function.
2) Request has 2 parameters :

```
- username
- password
- key(we will get into it later below, lets say key is 123456)
- form_key posted with form by default
```

3) Inside login function, magento checks if any user is present with these credentials. If yes, sets the current admin user to this user form which credentials were entered in form.
4) After this, magento redirects the control to adminhtml/index/index/key/123456
here you can see the key which we got in form is used to maintain the authenticity.

Now, if you want to make it ajax,

Create a custom controller lets say AjaxloginAction. Inside which you can write following function :

```
public function AjaxloginAction(){
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $username = $params['username'];
    $password = $params['password'];
    //call the model function here
    $flag = Mage::getModel('admin/session')->login($username, $password);
    if($flag == true){
        //user if logged in, do further redirection or processing
    }
    else{
        // invalid credentals, return warning on frontend
    }
}
```

To make sure session.php model does not redirect it by default, override it and change it to following :

```
public function login($username, $password, $request = null)
    {
        if (empty($username) || empty($password)) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            /** @var $user Mage_Admin_Model_User */
            $user = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
            $user->login($username, $password);
            if ($user->getId()) {
                $this->renewSession();

                if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->useSecretKey()) {
                    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->renewSecretUrls();
                }
                $this->setIsFirstPageAfterLogin(true);
                $this->setUser($user);
                $this->setAcl(Mage::getResourceModel('admin/acl')->loadAcl());

                $requestUri = $this->_getRequestUri($request);
                if ($requestUri) {
                    Mage::dispatchEvent('admin_session_user_login_success', array('user' => $user));
                    //header('Location: ' . $requestUri);
                    //exit;
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                return 'Invalid User Name or Password.';
            }
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            Mage::dispatchEvent('admin_session_user_login_failed',
                array('user_name' => $username, 'exception' => $e));
            if ($request && !$request->getParam('messageSent')) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                $request->setParam('messageSent', true);
            }
        }

        return $user;
    }

Hope this helps. :)
```

Comment: Thanks Blastfreak, I have few question:
1. About the custom controller, how could I create it? I don't want to create new module contains only one controller, should I? If I override IndexController to /local/Mage... can I put AjaxLoginAction inside it?
2. AjaxLoginAction, how can it called by Magento?
3. After I prepare response data for AJAX, what is the Url I call in this case? With AjaxLoginAction?

Answer (score 2):

1) Once you override IndexController.php, you can create the AjaxLoginAction inside it.
2) Inside your $.ajax, url you will specify is:

```
url : Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("mage_adminhtml/index/AjaxLogin");

//check once if the above url returns your action urls or not
```

3) Inside your controller you can send the output back to frontend in json using following :

```
$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($reply));
        return;

    //where reply can be a text or can be multidimentional arrray`enter code here`
```

Comment: Glad I could help you in this. Cheers. :)

Comment: An other small question, do you know how to create an url like this ? `/admin/index/ajax/login`, currently I believe our Url will look like this `admin/index/ajaxlogin`; And the redirect url in this case, could we get it from `...->login()` function?

Comment: In our case, our first goal is to take  the parameters to the ajaxlogin action. Inside ajaxlogin, we have already called login function from admin/session.php model. So that shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: Oh, thanks. When I browse to `/admin/index/ajaxlogin/` it is 404 not found, do you know why?

Comment: Admin urls need key with them to keep the authenticity. Create a url using magento function which will automatically append key in it

Comment: `Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("mage_adminhtml/index/ajaxlogin")` : If it is this url then it was not working...

Comment: I just found out that if you hit any of the actions in Adminhtml's IndexController.php, it will first take you to login page which will be problematic in your case. Hence, I will suggest instead of IndexController.php, create a custom admin controller in custom module and proceed further.

Comment: Also, one more thing about the backend url, for Adminhtml's Index controller, the generation of bakend url will be : Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("admin/index/ajaxlogin"); //Where the "admin" in the geturl params is your backend admin url which you hit after base url to go to backend. Just in case you need it in future :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69786/discussion-between-nntoan-and-blastfreak).